# What causes an EF (core) query to change during the course of the actual DB query in this geospatial query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, geospatial

I'm having a hard time getting geospatial queries to run on EF Core (net 5).

Model:

```cs
public class Pharmacy {
    [Column(TypeName = "geography (point)")]
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

Linq:

```cs
Point patientLocation = new Point(Convert.ToDouble(input.LatFilter), Convert.ToDouble(input.LongFilter)) { SRID = PharmacyConsts.SRID };
var pharmaciesQuery = _pharmacyRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.Location.Distance(patientLocation) <= 20000) // within 20km
                .OrderBy(x => x.Location.Distance(patientLocation))
                .Take(10)
                .IgnoreQueryFilters();
```

Expected Query (from `ToQueryString()`):

```sql
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 10;
DECLARE @__patientLocation_0 geometry = 0xE6100000010CB9FC87F4DB214640FD101B2C9C2353C0;

SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [p].[Id], [p].[Address1], [p].[Address2], [p].[Address3], [p].[City], [p].[CreationTime], [p].[CreatorUserId], [p].[DeleterUserId], [p].[DeletionTime], [p].[EmailAddress], [p].[FaxNumber], [p].[IsDeleted], [p].[LastModificationTime], [p].[LastModifierUserId], [p].[Latitude], [p].[Location], [p].[Longitude], [p].[PharmacyName], [p].[PharmacyStatus], [p].[PhoneExt], [p].[PhoneNumber], [p].[PostalCode], [p].[Province]
FROM [Pharmacies].[Pharmacy] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Location].STDistance(@__patientLocation_0) <= 20000.0E0
ORDER BY [p].[Location].STDistance(@__patientLocation_0)
```

Actual Query:

```sql
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 10,
        @__patientLocation_0 sql_variant = 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes';

SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [p].[Id], [p].[Address1], [p].[Address2], [p].[Address3], [p].[City], [p].[CreationTime], [p].[CreatorUserId], [p].[DeleterUserId], [p].[DeletionTime], [p].[EmailAddress], [p].[FaxNumber], [p].[IsDeleted], [p].[LastModificationTime], [p].[LastModifierUserId], [p].[Latitude], [p].[Location], [p].[Longitude], [p].[PharmacyName], [p].[PharmacyStatus], [p].[PhoneExt], [p].[PhoneNumber], [p].[PostalCode], [p].[Province]
FROM [Pharmacies].[Pharmacy] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Location].STDistance(@__patientLocation_0) <= 20000.0E0
ORDER BY [p].[Location].STDistance(@__patientLocation_0);
```

What is causing it to change the type and value of patientLocation from "geography" to "geometry" and then ultimately to "sql_variant"? ie. why does this not work?

EDIT 1:
Interestingly, if I remove the where clause - it stops failing in the same way. The param is kept the right type though the value may or may not be correct and the results are useless.

```cs
Point patientLocation = new Point(Convert.ToDouble(input.LatFilter), Convert.ToDouble(input.LongFilter)) { SRID = PharmacyConsts.SRID };

var pharmaciesQuery = _pharmacyRepository.GetAll()
    //.Where(x => x.Location.Distance(patientLocation) <= PharmacyConsts.DefaultDistanceCheck)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Location.Distance(patientLocation))
    .Take(10)
    .IgnoreQueryFilters();
```

`.ToQueryString()` gives me then:

```sql
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 10;
DECLARE @__patientLocation_0 geography = 0xE6100000010CFD101B2C9C2353C0B9FC87F4DB214640;

SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [p].[Id], [p].[Address1], [p].[Address2], [p].[Address3], [p].[City], [p].[CreationTime], [p].[CreatorUserId], [p].[DeleterUserId], [p].[DeletionTime], [p].[EmailAddress], [p].[FaxNumber], [p].[IsDeleted], [p].[LastModificationTime], [p].[LastModifierUserId], [p].[Location], [p].[PharmacyName], [p].[PharmacyStatus], [p].[PhoneExt], [p].[PhoneNumber], [p].[PostalCode], [p].[Province]
FROM [Pharmacies].[Pharmacy] AS [p]
ORDER BY [p].[Location].STDistance(@__patientLocation_0)
```

Comment: There is an edmx mapping file the maps the database tables to the c# classes.  It is part of the model.

Comment: This is code-first, no edmx.

Comment: The following page says "Create A Model" which creates the mapping file.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: The query is the same in both cases. What changes is the *patientLocation parameter*, which looks like it wasn't emitted at all. What was emitted looks like the output of an `Object.ToString()` call, as if `Point` wasn't recognized. Are you missing the appropriate NuGet packages perhaps? Have you added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite` ?

Comment: @jdweng not applicable here. Read up.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmm. Checking.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I know.  Read the question!!!  The Model is not matching the c# classes.  The OP said " What is causing it to change the type and value of patientLocation from "geography" to "geometry"

Comment: @jdweng I did, and saw the output of `Object.ToString()` which is why I suggested to the OP to check the packages. For some reason, `Point` is treated as a plain old class, not a spatial parameter. This isn't about models and MVC, spatial support was added to EF Core through NetTopologySuite. There's no EDMX or mapping files in EF Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  : There is still a mapping in Core and the mapping is wrong.  It may be called a schema instead of edmx, and it may be in memory.  But the mapping is wrong.

Comment: There is support @jdweng, it was covered on a dotnetconf video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHslY5rrxD0) but I'm trying to understand why that specific parameter type is changing to something wrong. You're not wrong, since there's a "mapping" somewhere, but it's not something I'm explicitly doing since I'm using code-first.

Comment: Check the model.  The Declare statement is a parameter in the query.  So it looks like the model is using a parameter which is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Have you used code-first much?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is confusing EF:

```
[Column(TypeName = "geography (point)")]
```

Try changing it to just `geography` without the *point* part.